# PDF page flip using Php?

Tags: php, pdf, animation

Is there any way to do a **flip page** animation for a PDF file? I am uploading a PDF file in my website and now while viewing it, I want the page flip effect, rather than scrolling up and down. Just like [this](http://pressmo.com/).

Comment: You have to use css3, javascript or flash for front end animations not php. - Pressmo uses flash.

Comment: I'd start with a web search of [flip page flash](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=flip+page+flash) - several Flash examples there!

Comment: Same as Tom, use some client side scripting. I think [this](http://line25.com/articles/super-cool-css-flip-effect-with-webkit-animation) may help. It's a flip effect for images; you can Google and modify the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done using Flash, CSS3, or JavaScript. PHP is server-side and therefore doesn't deal with client-side interactions like the one you're after.

The site you linked to offers a service that provides the effect you are looking for.

Comment: is there any converter available for this task?

Comment: The service you linked to is one! Alternatively here's an article with a list of jQuery plugins to do a similar task: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/5-free-jquery-page-flip-plugins-for-book-like-interfaces/

Comment: Thanks @Tom Walters, but these effects are only for divs. and the link i gave, i am looking for there service to integrate with my website

Comment: Well the service you linked to provides such instructions - create your eBook using the site and then embed it on your site.

Answer (score 1):

FlexPaper has a PHP library that helps you publish your PDFs to a page-flip book

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/docs_publishing_with_PHP.jsp

Answer (score 1):

You can try with heyzine, it has a  [library to convert the PDF to a magazine with page flip effects](http://heyzine.com).

You can use it either through links, jquery or php.